# How to avoid an infinite loop with Observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit(): void
    {  
    const source = this.categoryService.getCategories();
    console.log(source instanceof Observable);
    const example = source.map((categor) => categor.map((categories) => {
    const links = this.categoryService.countCategoryLinks(categories.id);
    const aff = example.merge(links).subscribe(linke => console.log(linke));
            return categories.id
        }));
    }
```

where **getCategories()** returns an observable.

On each item of this Observable, I get **categories.id** field to run another method called **countCategoryLinks(categories.id)** that also returns an Observable().

My problem is that : I only have 3 categories (ok), the countCategoryLinks() returns 3 items (ok) but the code above shows an **infinite loop in the console**.
Both methods started "manually" for testing purpose do not show any loop.

The problem really comes from the code above.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`example.merge(links)` <= you are using an observable created by the `map` callback in the map callback which would cause recursion (ie. loop back into itself). This is where it pays to use proper indention as it is easier to see.

```
ngOnInit(): void {  
    const source = this.categoryService.getCategories();
    console.log(source instanceof Observable);
    const example = source.map((categor) => categor.map((categories) => {
      const links = this.categoryService.countCategoryLinks(categories.id);

      // this line is the issue. You are using variable example which is being created by the callback this line of code is in
      const aff = example.merge(links).subscribe(linke => console.log(linke));
              return categories.id
          }));
}
```

I am thinking maybe you did not mean to still be inside of `map` at this point?

Comment: I am trying to merge the result of both methods... This is not the correct way to proceed? source contains 3 items. I get a field from source and start the other method, get an observable and merge it to the first...

Comment: @PhilippeCorrèges - you can either merge the results outside of the `map` call OR merge the result being generated IN the `map` call but merging the result of the function you are currently in will lead to an infinite loop (infinite recursion).

Comment: If I set **const aff = example.merge(links).subscribe(linke => console.log(linke));** outside of the map, there is not more visibility of links Observable().

Comment: @PhilippeCorrèges - Its not really clear what you are doing and why. You have `example` an observable of categories. Then you try to merge that for with each `links` observable per category in the map where you are actually creating the `example` observable. Seems like bad logic...

Comment: @PhilippeCorrèges - Also at that point in your code there is no need to `merge` because the results from the `source.map` are being realized at that point in time.

Comment: What I want to do: Get the Categories observable. For each item start a function that returns another Observable. At the end, only have one Observable.

Comment: @PhilippeCorrèges - see [flatMap](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/flatmap.html). That should do what you are trying to accomplish.